# Case response mail getting sent automatically when case is created

Tags: workflow, case

When a case is created, automatically a response mail is sent to the end users who created the case. I have checked all workflows, triggers, classes but I am not able to figure out on how the mail sending should be stopped. This is causing the case status to get changed to updated state.

Comment: Have you verified if you have [auto response rules](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=creating_auto-response_rules.htm&r=https:%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2F&type=5) set?

Comment: Yes. Auto response rules are not changed. Since past 2 days we are facing this issue.

Comment: So what does your auto response rule say? Does it send an email? Have you verified if there’s any process builder? These are few things you need to check. This is what one can recommend with the level of details you have provided

Comment: There is no process builder. Auto response rules fire when the support agent clicks a button called as "Send Response." Currently the email response is sent as soon as case is created